# Go - Convert 2 byte array into a uint16 value

Tags: go, byte

If I have a slice of bytes in Go, similar to this:

```
numBytes := []byte { 0xFF, 0x10 }
```

How would I convert it to it's `uint16` value (0xFF10, 65296)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you may use `binary.BigEndian.Uint16(numBytes)`
like this working sample code (with commented output):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    numBytes := []byte{0xFF, 0x10}
    u := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(numBytes)
    fmt.Printf("%#X %[1]v\n", u) // 0XFF10 65296
}
```

and see inside `binary.BigEndian.Uint16(b []byte)`:

```
func (bigEndian) Uint16(b []byte) uint16 {
    _ = b[1] // bounds check hint to compiler; see golang.org/issue/14808
    return uint16(b[1]) | uint16(b[0])<<8
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: out of interest why show BigEndian vs little which is more common ?

Answer (score 8):

To combine two bytes into uint16

```
x := uint16(numBytes[i])<<8 | uint16(numBytes[i+1])
```

where `i` is the starting position of the uint16. So if your array is always only two items it would be `x := uint16(numBytes[0])<<8 | uint16(numBytes[1])`

Comment: perfect, I was missing the cast to uint16. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a slice not an array - an array has a fixed size and would be declared like this `[2]byte`.

If you just have a 2 bytes slice, I wouldn't do anything fancy, I'd just do

```
numBytes := []byte{0xFF, 0x10}
n := int(numBytes[0])<<8 + int(numBytes[1])
fmt.Printf("n =0x%04X = %d\n", n, n)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iH-T788xv-)

**EDIT**: Just noticed you wanted `uint16` - replace `int` with that in the above!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following unsafe conversion:

```
*(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&numBytes[0])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).